# Insert Shortcode exactly at the end of the content

Tags: posts, functions, pages, shortcode, single

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[sharethis]"); ?> 
            <?php wp_related_posts()?>
```

There are 2 short codes above
1) share this plugin short code
2) related posts short code

now my QUESTION

first see this [LINK](http://www.orclage.com/best-free-antivirus-apps-android-smart-mobile-phones-tablets/)

At the ending of the post you can see the author box

i want want this author box below the above mentioned plugins

i tried these shortcode by keeping in single.php page but they didnt worked.

**Please help me, to insert both the shortcodes exactly below the content and above author box.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the *Fanciest Author Box* plugin ( *FAB* ).

This plugin is not open source so it's therefore difficult to give a detailed solution, since I can't look at the code inside it.

I assume it uses the `the_content` filter with some priority `p`.

To move the *FAB* box below the *Sharethis* & *Related-Posts*, you can then try this:

```
/**
 * Append sharethis & related-posts to the content
 * See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/116264/
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return string $content
 */
function the_content_wpse_116264( $content ){

    if( is_single() ){
        $content .= do_shortcode( '[sharethis]' ); 

        if( function_exists( 'wp_get_related_posts' ) )
            $content .= wp_get_related_posts();

    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'the_content_wpse_116264', 11, 1 );
```

where the priority `11` is hopefully lower than `p`.

If this still gives you problem regarding the priority, you could try to remove the `the_content` filter applied by *FAB* and add it again with the relevant priority.

Comment: Sir, when paste the given code in function.php file in dreamweaver editor it showed me error in related posts if condition,<br /> so i removed related posts code and just used Sharethis short code.<br />
so sir, please correct the related posts if condition
check the used code in my page sir
[link] http://www.orclage.com/how-to-block-ads-on-android-phone-without-root-applications/

Comment: aha, a missing parenthese `)`, sorry about that, it should be fixed now.

Comment: And it worked sir thank you very much, and sir can i get ur fb id (if u dont mind) :P

Comment: great to hear it worked and good luck with your project (ps: I'm not a user of FB)